# how to extract the text between a set of words and a symbol in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++

Looking to extract the text between `title='Go to last post:` and `'>` for all lines in the text file. Everything else should be deleted.

Here is a sample from a text file with the line that will be used:

https://myfurom/index.php/topic/251354/?view=getlastpost' title='Go to last post: The.Seven.Deadly.Sins-Volume.1'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do regex search with the following expression:

```
(?<=title='Go to last post:)(.*)(?='>)
```

This search will select all the content you want to extract, just copy and use it wherever you need.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thank you for your time and quick response